# What concepts in programming are useful in Electronics Engineering?

Tags: programming, c++

I am studying Electronics Engineering. I only took two 3 programming courses. The first 2 are in c++ and I learnt up till pointers, classes and the basics of data structures. The third is mips Assembly language. I need to know if learning more about data structures, Algorithms and discrete mathematics will help me in the field of Electronics Engineering. I will not have the chance to study these topics in my university, so if they are important I can self study them.

Comment: C / Assembler is probably useful to give an appreciation of how CPU's are working at a low level, these days you don't get much electronics that doesn't have some software element to it so I would not assume that you'll never touch software again...

Comment: When I read the question title, I didn't think this was going to be a constructive question. After reading the question, however, I think it is probably a good one. I'm going to edit the title to try and give it a more on-topic feel.

Comment: Not a concept in programming, but since you mentioned discrete mathematics: If I had it to do over, I would have studied more Calculus prior to college.

Comment: Def recommend Data Structures & C++ (Object-Oriented Programming), in addition to the essential C / Assembly. If you're going to skip discrete structures (Which isn't pure calculus) go over graph theory.

Comment: Electrical engineering is a huge field.  There is no good answer to this question.  I can't think of a programming concept that won't be useful to some extent.

Comment: All of them!  :)   But C/C++/Assembler are my top picks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions *(with Wikipedia links)* from my own experience doing both programming and hobby-level electronics engineering:

- **[Assembly code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language)** (frequently encountered in microcontrollers)
- **[State machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)** (a programming pattern aka finite state machine (FSM) which can be used in designing logic circuits as well as higher level applications)
- **[Bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)** (working with bits is equally useful in programming and electronics)
- **[Truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29)** Useful for arranging logic gates in electronics as well as working with multiple booleans in code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert but the following concepts have been useful for me in several ocassions:

[Queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) (For processing big data quantities without miss any information, logging systems, manage multiple process).

State machines, like said JYelton.

[Object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (Help to reuse code and allow expand the functionality easily, many APIs use this programming paradigm).